# Simulate Mouse dragging in Delphi

Tags: delphi, mouse

I have a Delphi Form and on it an TWebbroser with a google map. I want to simulate a Mouse Drag. Left klick, move mouse to another position, release mouse. It should drag the Map from left to right.
I have tried this, but the map does not drag.

```
procedure MoveMouse (X,Y,Speed: Integer);
var
Maus : TPoint;
mx, my, nx, ny, len : double;
begin
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);

if Speed < 1 then Speed := 1;

GetCursorPos(Maus);
mx := maus.x;
my := maus.y;

While (mx<>x)OR(my<>y) Do begin
nx := x-mx;
ny := y-my;
len := sqrt(nx*nx + ny*ny);

if(len<=1)Then begin
  mx:=x;
  my:=y;
end
else begin
  nx := nx / (len*0.5);
  ny := ny / (len*0.5);
  mx := mx + nx;
  my := my + ny;
end;
Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, Round(mx)+50,Round(my), 0, GetMessageExtraInfo);
//    SetCursorPos(Round(mx),Round(my));
Sleep(Speed);
end;
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

end;
```

Please, can anyone help me? Many thanks!

Comment: Use some JavaScript API instead of this ugly approach. You can grab for instance OpenLayers JavaScript library. It support many providers with the same script.

Comment: Have you tried using `Application.ProcessMessages;` just before your `Sleep()` call?

Comment: this is a general problem and not a problem of the Map. when I try to drag other content in web browser (a flash game or something similar) is the same problem. 
Application.ProcessMessages; the problem is the same :(

Comment: Give the OpenLayers a try; it's a nice library. You'd just load this [`HTML file`](http://pastebin.com/4Gcssd8x) into your `TWebBrowser` and use a code [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/JAHWBbgj). There are many other useful functions you can use in your application. And, it doesn't need to have GoogleMaps API key.

Comment: Many thanks for the advise for OpenLayers. I have saved your Codesnippets for my other project.
For my current Project i use this solution:

    procedure TForm1.MoveLeft;
    var
    p2 : Tpoint;
    begin
      p2 := clienttoscreen(point(20,100));
      SetCursorPos(p2.x, p2.y);
      Mouse_Event(MouseEventF_LeftDown, p2.x, p2.y, 0, 0);
      sleep(200);
      Mouse_Event(MouseEventF_LeftUp or MouseEventF_Move, 600, 0, 0, 0);
     end;